# How can I convert iso-8859-1 to utf8 correctly?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I need to write  a response stream to a file. The stream contains an encoded page (iso-8859-1).

This is my code:

```
...

using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tmpFilePath))
{
  using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(answer, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
  {

    string line = "";
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {

      // try to decode
      string decoded_line = decode(line);

      writer.WriteLine(decoded_line);
    }

  }

}

...


string decode(string message) 
{
  string result = "";

  Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
  Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

  byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(message);
  byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(iso, utf8, isoBytes);

  result = utf8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

  return result;
}
```

The problem is that decode() is not working

[image]

How can I convert iso-8859-1 to utf8 correctly?

UPDATE

I rely on fiddler to get the content-type:

[image]

Comment: The contents of 'message' doesn't look like valid ISO-8859-1

Comment: Delete your decode() method, the decoding and encoding is already taken care of by the StreamReader/Writer.  If you still have trouble then you didn't guess the encoding of the input file correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Given the situation it should be enough to:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tmpFilePath, Ecoding.UTF8))
{
 using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(answer, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
 {
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
   {
      writer.WriteLine(decoded_line);
   }
 }    
}
```

If this doesn't work, check your data. How does the (first) line look in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You're decoding twice - you already specified the encoding when creating the StreamReader. The resulting string should already be properly decoded.

This doesn't explain why `message` looks like that - it should look like an ordinary string. Are you sure the file you're reading contains what you think it contains?

Answer (score -1):

You can see sample .NET conversion code any encoding to any encoding working as-is with Azure Function, but possibly could be re-hosted anywhere .NET can run:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david_burgs_blog/support-non-utf-payloads-in-logic-app-with-a-conversion-azure-function

This sample protects the input and output content in base64 encoding to ensure .NET unicode assumption for string type doesn't get in the way.

```
 var outputBytes = Encoding.Convert(srcEncoding: inputEncoding, dstEncoding: encodingOutput, bytes: Convert.FromBase64String(input));
...
text = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes)
```

The byte arrays may as well be read and written directly to a file handle instead.