# How to generate Windows 1250 encoded content using LogicApp in Azure

Tags: json, utf-8, character-encoding, azure-logic-apps

As I know, LogicApps works on UTF-8 character set, and I need to compose the file in the Windows 1250 code page. How can I do this?
The json_encode function doesn't appear in the built-in Expressions/Functions inside the LogicApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not File Encoding in Logic App, contents can be encoded in whatever format you need and the app may or may not even be aware of this.

If you have a specific situation, you could do a content type conversion with Azure Functions using stream writer. Here is a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2018/02/27/support-non-utf-payloads-in-logic-app-with-a-conversion-azure-function/) and a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540936/how-can-i-convert-iso-8859-1-to-utf8-correctly) about conversion.

And the logic app supports Azure Functions integration.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thx for input. This is definitely what I am looking for but I have some difficulties to use it. When creating new Azure Function triggered with HTTP request and replace the default code with the one you referred to, in the run.csx file, I got some compilation errors when trying to use it with the example provided. Any tip how to use it?

Comment: I have used Visual Studio 2017, create a project, selected Function in Azure, build it and published it. All works OK. Thx